# SQLAlchemy returns None both when result is NULL and empty se

Tags: sqlalchemy

Is this to be expected?

The SQLAlchemy scalar method returns a None value both when no row is returned, and when one raw is returned,but with 'NULL'. I now exclude the NULL value with my SQL statement but was surprised by this result.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`Query.one`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.one) method instead.

In this case it will return `None` if the query results in NULL or raise `NoResultFound` if there is no result at all. The `MultipleResultsFound` exception is possible, too (like in `Query.scalar`).